# How can I change the style of the first component if it is duplicated many times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

there is a component duplicated many times in another component. There is a button in this component. How do I change the style of the first component when clicking on it

---

```
<div>
<Checkbox />
<Checkbox />
<Checkbox />
<Checkbox />
<Checkbox />
<Checkbox />
</div>
```

Comment: using state or using refs

Comment: I need only 1 component to change, and the others to remain unchanged.

Comment: Would be useful if you showed the code for the Checkbox components, but you could use the :first-child pseudo-class

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the optional props "style" from the parent component.
for example:

```
<div>
 <Checkbox style={{
   color: "blue"
  }} />
 <Checkbox />
 <Checkbox />
 <Checkbox />
 <Checkbox />
 <Checkbox />
</div>
```

and that's how you can handle this in your Checkbox component -

```
const Checkbox = ({
 style = {}
}) => {
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container, ...style]} ></View> 
  )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to toggle the style on mouse click.

Comment: He can toggle the style with the mouse click. 
For example:
 
const onClickHandler = () => setChecked(!checked);

and on the component

 <Checkbox style={checked ? {
   color: "blue"
  } : {}} />

Answer (score 1):

You'll require state somewhere but depending on what component controls it will depend on where it goes. Ashish has hinted at one solution (controlling the state from the parent) but probably the easiest method is to have the `<Checkbox />` component control it instead.

In this example I have an optional `styleCanChange` prop (defaults to `false`) that tells the component whether or not to use the `blue` style or not. I've added labels for completeness.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {
  return (
    <main>
      <Checkbox label="One" styleCanChange />
      <Checkbox label="Two" />
      <Checkbox label="Three" />
      <Checkbox label="Four" />
    </main>
  );
}

// Default `styleCanChange` to false
function Checkbox({ label, styleCanChange = false }) {
  
  // Set state of the checkbox
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  
  // Set the state when the box is checked
  function handleChange() {
    setChecked(prev => !prev);
  }
  
  // Create a class depending on whether the box is
  // checked and styleCanChange is true
  const cn = checked && styleCanChange ? 'blue' : '';
  
  return (
    <div className={cn}>
      <input
        id={label}
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={handleChange}
        checked={checked}
      />
      <label htmlFor={label}>{label}</label>
    </div>
  );
}

const node = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(node);
root.render(<Example />);
```

```css
.blue { background-color: lightblue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```